# Laplacian as the divergence of the gradient - in spherical coordinates

Tags: vector-analysis

Say I have an arbitrary function $f(r,\theta,\phi)$. If I take the gradient in spherical coordinates it reads
\begin{equation}
\nabla f= \hat{\bf r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + {\bf \hat{\theta}}\frac1r\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta} + {\bf \hat{\phi}} \frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}.
\end{equation}
By definition, $\Delta f \equiv \nabla \cdot\nabla f$, so naively one would conclude:
\begin{align}
\Delta f &= \left[\hat{\bf r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + {\bf \hat{\theta}}\frac1r\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + {\bf \hat{\phi}} \frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right] \bullet\left[\hat{\bf r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + {\bf \hat{\theta}}\frac1r\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta} + {\bf \hat{\phi}} \frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\right]\\
&=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\theta^2} + {\bf \hat{\phi}} \frac1{r^2\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\phi^2},
\end{align}
however this is incorrect:
\begin{equation}
\Delta f = \frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[r^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial f}\right] + \frac1{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left[\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right] + \frac1{r^2\sin^2\theta} \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\phi}.
\end{equation}
Why does this not hold, i.e. what assumption has been omitted?

Comment: No $\hat \phi$ on the second expression. Also $\frac{\partial f}{\partial f}$ on the real laplacian should probably be something else.

Comment: The second nabla works on the first with the product and chain rules of differentiation so you can't just group them up like that.

Comment: @mathreadler That I can see. But what formal steps should I take to derive the right expression?

Answer (score 0):

U have the incorrect expression for the divergence operator!!!! It reads as
$$\nabla\cdot\bf{G}=\frac{1}{h_{1}h_{2}h_{3}}\Big(\frac{\partial(h_{2}h_{3}G_{1})}{\partial{x_{1}}}+\frac{\partial(h_{1}h_{3}G_{2})}{\partial{x_{2}}}+\frac{\partial(h_{2}h_{1}G_{3})}{\partial{x_{3}}}\Big)$$
Where $h_{i}=\sqrt{g_{ii}}$ are scale factors of the coordinate system. For spherical coordinates $h_{r}=1$, $h_{\theta}=r\sin\varphi$ and $h_{\varphi}=r$. However, your expression of the gradient is correct. Take the correct operator and you'll get the result!

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify on why the notation $\nabla\cdot{\bf G}$ is allowed? This is clearly not the "inner product of $\nabla$ and $\bf G$"???

Comment: It is miss conceptual really. This is not an inner product, as $\nabla$ is not a vector in a sense. The proper way to write is $div[\bf{G}]$. I think this notation is popular because of some educative purposes, say to emphasize that the result is scalar....